# Adding group columns in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame has 9 rows and one column (X). I need to add another column (Y) that assign (create a group) for the first column using integer number for each 3 rows (observations).
Example:
[image]

Comment: `(seq(length(df$x))-1)%/%3`

Comment: Thanks Wen. It worked.

Comment: Yw:-) happy coding

Answer (score 0):

```
data.frame(x=1:9,y=rep(1:3,each=3))
```